# Sending commands to an open instance of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interop

I have the need to send commands (I.e Build, Debug) to a running instance (process) of visual studio created by my application.

Is it possible/does visual studio accept receiving commands using `Process.StandardInput` and can i do what i want be using this method? I cannot find anything regarding this by googling.

Alternatively, if no such method exists, is there a standard way to interop with Visual Studio from an external application and how do i do this.

The one alternative i can think of is grabbing a reference to the Visual Studio window somehow and sending key commands, triggering shortcuts to do what i want. though this seems like a last resort..

Comment: Is there a special reason you want to interface with an instance of Visual Studio rather than MSBuild directly?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356583/getting-envdte-dte-instance-outside-visual-studio-ide

Comment: Thanks @SergeyVlasov that looks to be exactly what i need